# I want to search a number from a column from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created one database with 3 columns and now I want to search a number which I give from `EditText` with a message that it is present in that column or not

This  is my database

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "Tracker";
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final static String TABLE_NAME = "registration";
    private final static String COL_ID = "id";

    private final static String COL_name = "Name";
    private final static String COL_email = "Email_id";
    private static final String COL_contact = "ContactNo";

    private static final String createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL_name + " TEXT," +
            COL_email + " TEXT," +
            COL_contact + " TEXT)";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        //1. Initialised database
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(createTableQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long insert( User user) {
        // 1. init database object
        SQLiteDatabase DataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. init ContentValues object
        ContentValues row = new ContentValues();

        row.put(COL_name, user.getName1());
        row.put(COL_email, user.getMail1());
        row.put(COL_contact, user.getCon1());

       // row.put(KEY_ListItem,getListItem(cur));

        //3. insert row into table
        long id = DataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, row);
        //4. disconnect database
        DataBase.close();
        if (id != 0) {
            return id;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

And now I want to search a number from this activity

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tv1;
    //    EditText conNo;

    private DBHelper databaseHelper;
    public final static String KEY = "position";
    TelephonyManager tel;

    String phoneNumber;
    ListView listview;
    ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();

    EditText conNo;
    Button Search;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_test);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    conNo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Search= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}}
```

When I edit in `conNo` and after pressing search button it should check a number from `contactno` column.

Please suggest me possible ways to solve this issue.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

Apply to below Query fro searching number fro mthe column in sqlite DB :

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  " + ContactNo + " = '" + EDIT_TEXT_NUMBER +"'";
```

Comment: EDIT_TEXT_NUMBER it is in another  class , so what should i write

Comment: are you beginner in android

Comment: create a parameterised method in sqlite DB class for getting number from the table and call it in EDIT_TEXT_NUMBER class with contact number parameter. If still any problem ask?

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in DB class like

```
public static function getNumber(edit_text_number){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  " + ContactNo + " = '" + edit_text_number +"'";
    return db.execSQL(selectQuery);
}
```

And call this function from the activity like

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text)
result = getNumber(editText.getText().toString())
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
        String contact = conNo.getText().toString();
        if (databaseHelper.searchPass(contact)!=contact)
        {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,"Not Ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

Comment: i wrote this in my main activity and in dbclass i wrote this,

Comment: public String searchPass(String name1){

        SQLiteDatabase DataBase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  " + COL_contact + " = '" + name1 +"'";


        Cursor result=DataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        if (result.getCount()<1)
        {
            result.close();
            return "Not Exist";
        }
        result.moveToFirst();
        // String password=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_Password));
        result.close();
        return name1;

    }

Answer (score 1):

Check below code,

```
     public boolean ifNumberExists(String strNumber)
     {
         Cursor cursor = null;
         String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  " + ContactNo + " = '" + strNumber +"'";
          cursor= db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
          boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
          cursor.close();
          return exists;
     }
```

**For Main Activity**

```
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

             if(dbObject.ifNumberExists(conNo.getEditableText()))
              {
                  // Toast Number Exists
              }
              else
              {
                 // Number not Exists
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: and in main activity?

Comment: In main activity inside search button click event just call this method as dbObject.ifNumberExists(conNo.getEditableText());

Comment: m not getting it pls simplify it,because i want to show toast msg also that no. is present in that list or not

Comment: replace it with db

Comment: databaseHelper=new DBHelper(TestActivity.this);

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       //  databaseHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

        if(databaseHelper.ifNumberExists(conNo.getText().toString()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,"Not Ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

    }

Comment: public boolean ifNumberExists(String strNumber)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase DataBase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  " + COL_contact + " = '" + strNumber +"'";
        cursor= DataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
        cursor.close();
        return exists;
    }

Comment: change this "TestActivity.this" by "getApplicationContext()" in query and toast it will not work

Comment: then what shold i use in place of toast

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: now i want to compare list item with the same n my code is

Comment: listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
              if(databaseHelper.ifNumberExists(item))